# Facebook sending authorized signed_request after removing app

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-canvas, facebook-authorization

I'm developing a facebook canvas app and for testing purposes, sometimes I go to my account settings and delete the app (to force re-authorizing the app).

The problem I'm facing is that even after I do this, when I access the app, facebook still sends me a signed_request with user_id and a valid oauth_token, as I had authorized the app.

Is there any cache or delay for facebook to take my removal into account?

What could have been happening?

Comment: What technology are you using? maybe your code is checking the returned signed_request and replacing its values with cashed ones?

Comment: I'm using django/python and django-facebook app. But I'm catching this  when the http requests get to my application, before any processing.

Comment: I am not sure what's wrong, but ideally you should reset (refresh) your session with what Facebook is providing you to maintain the login status, and then act accordingly.